# scaleMode .fill not filling the scene view on iPad

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3, xcasset

I created my game using the Universal images of dimensions 1136x640 (@2x) and 2208x1242 (@3x) for my start background. I changed the `scaleMode` property to `.fill` for `iPad` but it just fills the center with black borders all around. I thought `.fill` was suppose to extend the width and height to fill the scene view.
I found a sample universal project that I tested and the images scaled with `.fill` for the iPad. They used, 568x320 (@1x), 1136x640 (@2x) and 1704x960 (@3x) for their images. I copied the images into my project and tested for `iPad` and still got the black surrounding.

1. What is causing the black border for the `iPad`?
2. What explicit dimensions should I use for my universal game for `@1x`, `@2x`, `@3x` background so that when I set `scaleMode` to `.fill` for `iPad` it will fill the scenes width and height?

Below is my how I set the `StartBackgroundScene` scene in the `GameViewController`

```
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    let skView = self.view as? SKView

    if skView?.scene == nil  {
        skView?.showsFPS = true
        skView?.showsNodeCount = true
        skView?.showsPhysics = false
        skView?.ignoresSiblingOrder = false

        let startBackgroundScene = StartBackgroundScene(size: skView!.bounds.size) 
        startBackgroundScene.scaleMode = .fill
        skView?.presentScene(startBackgroundScene)
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the scale node to .aspectFill, or other scale modes?

Comment: Also, for making the game universal, look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34864533/6728196